# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by AddLiquidity

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[That was the problem with the error I got in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcaKG.png)

The function is called on form submission. at first, it is working as expected but when calling this function on form submit. I get this following error.index.js:1 Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by null. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks:

```html
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import { BigNumber } from '@ethersproject/bignumber'
import { TransactionResponse } from '@ethersproject/providers'
import { Currency, currencyEquals, ETHER, TokenAmount, WETH } from '@pancakeswap-libs/sdk'
import { Button, CardBody, AddIcon, Text as UIKitText } from '@pancakeswap-libs/uikit'
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'
import { LightCard } from 'components/Card'
import { AutoColumn, ColumnCenter } from 'components/Column'
import TransactionConfirmationModal, { ConfirmationModalContent } from 'components/TransactionConfirmationModal'
import CardNav from 'components/CardNav'
import CurrencyInputPanel from 'components/CurrencyInputPanel'
import DoubleCurrencyLogo from 'components/DoubleLogo'
import { AddRemoveTabs } from 'components/NavigationTabs'
import { MinimalPositionCard } from 'components/PositionCard'
import Row, { RowBetween, RowFlat } from 'components/Row'

import { PairState } from 'data/Reserves'
import { useActiveWeb3React } from 'hooks'
import { useCurrency } from 'hooks/Tokens'
import { ApprovalState, useApproveCallback } from 'hooks/useApproveCallback'
import { Field } from 'state/mint/actions'
import { useDerivedMintInfo, useMintActionHandlers, useMintState } from 'state/mint/hooks'

import { useTransactionAdder } from 'state/transactions/hooks'
import { useIsExpertMode, useUserDeadline, useUserSlippageTolerance } from 'state/user/hooks'
import { calculateGasMargin, calculateSlippageAmount, getRouterContract } from 'utils'
import { maxAmountSpend } from 'utils/maxAmountSpend'
import { wrappedCurrency } from 'utils/wrappedCurrency'
import { currencyId } from 'utils/currencyId'
import Pane from 'components/Pane'
import ConnectWalletButton from 'components/ConnectWalletButton'
import useI18n from 'hooks/useI18n'
import AppBody from '../AppBody'
import { Dots, Wrapper } from '../Pool/styleds'
import { ConfirmAddModalBottom } from './ConfirmAddModalBottom'
import { PoolPriceBar } from './PoolPriceBar'
import { ROUTER_ADDRESS } from '../../constants'

export default function AddLiquidity({
  match: {
    params: { currencyIdA, currencyIdB },
  },
  history,
}: RouteComponentProps<{ currencyIdA?: string; currencyIdB?: string }>) {
  const { account, chainId, library } = useActiveWeb3React()
  const currencyA = useCurrency(currencyIdA)
  const currencyB = useCurrency(currencyIdB)
  const TranslateString = useI18n()

  const oneCurrencyIsWBNB = Boolean(
    chainId &&
    ((currencyA && currencyEquals(currencyA, WETH[chainId])) ||
      (currencyB && currencyEquals(currencyB, WETH[chainId])))
  )
  const expertMode = useIsExpertMode()

  // mint state
  const { independentField, typedValue, otherTypedValue } = useMintState()
  const {
    dependentField,
    currencies,
    pair,
    pairState,
    currencyBalances,
    parsedAmounts,
    price,
    noLiquidity,
    liquidityMinted,
    poolTokenPercentage,
    error,
  } = useDerivedMintInfo(currencyA ?? undefined, currencyB ?? undefined)
  const { onFieldAInput, onFieldBInput } = useMintActionHandlers(noLiquidity)

  const isValid = !error

  // modal and loading
  const [showConfirm, setShowConfirm] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [attemptingTxn, setAttemptingTxn] = useState<boolean>(false) // clicked confirm

  // txn values
  const [deadline] = useUserDeadline() // custom from users settings
  const [allowedSlippage] = useUserSlippageTolerance() // custom from users
  const [txHash, setTxHash] = useState<string>('')

  // get formatted amounts
  const formattedAmounts = {
    [independentField]: typedValue,
    [dependentField]: noLiquidity ? otherTypedValue : parsedAmounts[dependentField]?.toSignificant(6) ?? '',
  }

  // get the max amounts user can add
  const maxAmounts: { [field in Field]?: TokenAmount } = [Field.CURRENCY_A, Field.CURRENCY_B].reduce(
    (accumulator, field) => {
      return {
        ...accumulator,
        [field]: maxAmountSpend(currencyBalances[field]),
      }
    },
    {}
  )

  const atMaxAmounts: { [field in Field]?: TokenAmount } = [Field.CURRENCY_A, Field.CURRENCY_B].reduce(
    (accumulator, field) => {
      return {
        ...accumulator,
        [field]: maxAmounts[field]?.equalTo(parsedAmounts[field] ?? '0'),
      }
    },
    {}
  )

  // check whether the user has approved the router on the tokens
  const [approvalA, approveACallback] = useApproveCallback(parsedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_A], ROUTER_ADDRESS)
  const [approvalB, approveBCallback] = useApproveCallback(parsedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_B], ROUTER_ADDRESS)

  const addTransaction = useTransactionAdder()

  async function onAdd() {
    if (!chainId || !library || !account) return
    const router = getRouterContract(chainId, library, account)

    const { [Field.CURRENCY_A]: parsedAmountA, [Field.CURRENCY_B]: parsedAmountB } = parsedAmounts
    if (!parsedAmountA || !parsedAmountB || !currencyA || !currencyB) {
      return
    }

    const amountsMin = {
      [Field.CURRENCY_A]: calculateSlippageAmount(parsedAmountA, noLiquidity ? 0 : allowedSlippage)[0],
      [Field.CURRENCY_B]: calculateSlippageAmount(parsedAmountB, noLiquidity ? 0 : allowedSlippage)[0],
    }

    const deadlineFromNow = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000) + deadline

    let estimate
    let method: (...args: any) => Promise<TransactionResponse>
    let args: Array<string | string[] | number>
    let value: BigNumber | null
    if (currencyA === ETHER || currencyB === ETHER) {
      const tokenBIsBNB = currencyB === ETHER
      estimate = router.estimateGas.addLiquidityETH
      method = router.addLiquidityETH
      args = [
        wrappedCurrency(tokenBIsBNB ? currencyA : currencyB, chainId)?.address ?? '', // token
        (tokenBIsBNB ? parsedAmountA : parsedAmountB).raw.toString(), // token desired
        amountsMin[tokenBIsBNB ? Field.CURRENCY_A : Field.CURRENCY_B].toString(), // token min
        amountsMin[tokenBIsBNB ? Field.CURRENCY_B : Field.CURRENCY_A].toString(), // eth min
        account,
        deadlineFromNow,
      ]
      value = BigNumber.from((tokenBIsBNB ? parsedAmountB : parsedAmountA).raw.toString())
    } else {
      estimate = router.estimateGas.addLiquidity
      method = router.addLiquidity
      args = [
        wrappedCurrency(currencyA, chainId)?.address ?? '',
        wrappedCurrency(currencyB, chainId)?.address ?? '',
        parsedAmountA.raw.toString(),
        parsedAmountB.raw.toString(),
        amountsMin[Field.CURRENCY_A].toString(),
        amountsMin[Field.CURRENCY_B].toString(),
        account,
        deadlineFromNow,
      ]
      value = null
    }

    setAttemptingTxn(true)
    // const aa = await estimate(...args, value ? { value } : {})
    await estimate(...args, value ? { value } : {})
      .then((estimatedGasLimit) =>
        method(...args, {
          ...(value ? { value } : {}),
          gasLimit: calculateGasMargin(estimatedGasLimit),
        }).then((response) => {
          setAttemptingTxn(false)

          addTransaction(response, {
            summary: `Add ${parsedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.toSignificant(3)} ${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.symbol
              } and ${parsedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.toSignificant(3)} ${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.symbol}`,
          })

          setTxHash(response.hash)
        })
      )
      .catch((e) => {
        setAttemptingTxn(false)
        // we only care if the error is something _other_ than the user rejected the tx
        if (e?.code !== 4001) {
          console.error(e)
        }
      })
  }

  const modalHeader = () => {
    return noLiquidity ? (
      <AutoColumn gap="20px">
        <LightCard mt="20px" borderRadius="20px">
          <RowFlat>
            <UIKitText fontSize="48px" mr="8px">
              {`${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.symbol}/${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.symbol}`}
            </UIKitText>
            <DoubleCurrencyLogo
              currency0={currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]}
              currency1={currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]}
              size={30}
            />
          </RowFlat>
        </LightCard>
      </AutoColumn>
    ) : (
        <AutoColumn gap="20px">
          <RowFlat style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
            <UIKitText fontSize="48px" mr="8px">
              {liquidityMinted?.toSignificant(6)}
            </UIKitText>
            <DoubleCurrencyLogo
              currency0={currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]}
              currency1={currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]}
              size={30}
            />
          </RowFlat>
          <Row>
            <UIKitText fontSize="24px">
              {`${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.symbol}/${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.symbol} Pool Tokens`}
            </UIKitText>
          </Row>
          <UIKitText small textAlign="left" padding="8px 0 0 0 " style={{ fontStyle: 'italic' }}>
            {`Output is estimated. If the price changes by more than ${allowedSlippage / 100
              }% your transaction will revert.`}
          </UIKitText>
        </AutoColumn>
      )
  }

  const modalBottom = () => {
    return (
      <ConfirmAddModalBottom
        price={price}
        currencies={currencies}
        parsedAmounts={parsedAmounts}
        noLiquidity={noLiquidity}
        onAdd={onAdd}
        poolTokenPercentage={poolTokenPercentage}
      />
    )
  }

  const pendingText = `Supplying ${parsedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.toSignificant(6)} ${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.symbol
    } and ${parsedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.toSignificant(6)} ${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.symbol}`

  const handleCurrencyASelect = useCallback(
    (currA: Currency) => {
      const newCurrencyIdA = currencyId(currA)
      if (newCurrencyIdA === currencyIdB) {
        history.push(`/add/${currencyIdB}/${currencyIdA}`)
      } else {
        history.push(`/add/${newCurrencyIdA}/${currencyIdB}`)
      }
    },
    [currencyIdB, history, currencyIdA]
  )
  const handleCurrencyBSelect = useCallback(
    (currB: Currency) => {
      const newCurrencyIdB = currencyId(currB)
      if (currencyIdA === newCurrencyIdB) {
        if (currencyIdB) {
          history.push(`/add/${currencyIdB}/${newCurrencyIdB}`)
        } else {
          history.push(`/add/${newCurrencyIdB}`)
        }
      } else {
        history.push(`/add/${currencyIdA || 'BNB'}/${newCurrencyIdB}`)
      }
    },
    [currencyIdA, history, currencyIdB]
  )

  const handleDismissConfirmation = useCallback(() => {
    setShowConfirm(false)
    // if there was a tx hash, we want to clear the input
    if (txHash) {
      onFieldAInput('')
    }
    setTxHash('')
  }, [onFieldAInput, txHash])

  return (
    <>
      <CardNav activeIndex={1} />
      <AppBody>
        <AddRemoveTabs adding />
        <Wrapper>
          <TransactionConfirmationModal
            isOpen={showConfirm}
            onDismiss={handleDismissConfirmation}
            attemptingTxn={attemptingTxn}
            hash={txHash}
            content={() => (
              <ConfirmationModalContent
                title={
                  noLiquidity
                    ? TranslateString(1154, 'You are creating a pool')
                    : TranslateString(1156, 'You will receive')
                }
                onDismiss={handleDismissConfirmation}
                topContent={modalHeader}
                bottomContent={modalBottom}
              />
            )}
            pendingText={pendingText}
          />
          <CardBody>
            <AutoColumn gap="20px">
              {noLiquidity && (
                <ColumnCenter>
                  <Pane>
                    <AutoColumn gap="12px">
                      <UIKitText>{TranslateString(1158, 'You are the first liquidity provider.')}</UIKitText>
                      <UIKitText>
                        {TranslateString(1160, 'The ratio of tokens you add will set the price of this pool.')}
                      </UIKitText>
                      <UIKitText>
                        {TranslateString(1162, 'Once you are happy with the rate click supply to review.')}
                      </UIKitText>
                    </AutoColumn>
                  </Pane>
                </ColumnCenter>
              )}
              <CurrencyInputPanel
                value={formattedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_A]}
                onUserInput={onFieldAInput}
                onMax={() => {
                  onFieldAInput(maxAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.toExact() ?? '')
                }}
                onCurrencySelect={handleCurrencyASelect}
                showMaxButton={!atMaxAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_A]}
                currency={currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]}
                id="add-liquidity-input-tokena"
                showCommonBases={false}
              />
              <ColumnCenter>
                <AddIcon color="textSubtle" />
              </ColumnCenter>
              <CurrencyInputPanel
                value={formattedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_B]}
                onUserInput={onFieldBInput}
                onCurrencySelect={handleCurrencyBSelect}
                onMax={() => {
                  onFieldBInput(maxAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.toExact() ?? '')
                }}
                showMaxButton={!atMaxAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_B]}
                currency={currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]}
                id="add-liquidity-input-tokenb"
                showCommonBases={false}
              />
              {currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A] && currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B] && pairState !== PairState.INVALID && (
                <div>
                  <UIKitText
                    style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase', fontWeight: 600 }}
                    color="textSubtle"
                    fontSize="12px"
                    mb="2px"
                  >
                    {noLiquidity
                      ? TranslateString(1164, 'Initial prices and pool share')
                      : TranslateString(1166, 'Prices and pool share')}
                  </UIKitText>
                  <Pane>
                    <PoolPriceBar
                      currencies={currencies}
                      poolTokenPercentage={poolTokenPercentage}
                      noLiquidity={noLiquidity}
                      price={price}
                    />
                  </Pane>
                </div>
              )}

              {!account ? (
                <ConnectWalletButton width="100%" />
              ) : (
                  <AutoColumn gap="md">
                    {(approvalA === ApprovalState.NOT_APPROVED ||
                      approvalA === ApprovalState.PENDING ||
                      approvalB === ApprovalState.NOT_APPROVED ||
                      approvalB === ApprovalState.PENDING) &&
                      isValid && (
                        <RowBetween>
                          {approvalA !== ApprovalState.APPROVED && (
                            <Button
                              onClick={approveACallback}
                              disabled={approvalA === ApprovalState.PENDING}
                              style={{ width: approvalB !== ApprovalState.APPROVED ? '48%' : '100%' }}
                            >
                              {approvalA === ApprovalState.PENDING ? (
                                <Dots>Approving {currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.symbol}</Dots>
                              ) : (
                                  `Approve ${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_A]?.symbol}`
                                )}
                            </Button>
                          )}
                          {approvalB !== ApprovalState.APPROVED && (
                            <Button
                              onClick={approveBCallback}
                              disabled={approvalB === ApprovalState.PENDING}
                              style={{ width: approvalA !== ApprovalState.APPROVED ? '48%' : '100%' }}
                            >
                              {approvalB === ApprovalState.PENDING ? (
                                <Dots>Approving {currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.symbol}</Dots>
                              ) : (
                                  `Approve ${currencies[Field.CURRENCY_B]?.symbol}`
                                )}
                            </Button>
                          )}
                        </RowBetween>
                      )}
                    <Button
                      onClick={() => {
                        if (expertMode) {
                          onAdd()
                        } else {
                          setShowConfirm(true)
                        }
                      }}
                      disabled={!isValid || approvalA !== ApprovalState.APPROVED || approvalB !== ApprovalState.APPROVED}
                      variant={
                        !isValid && !!parsedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_A] && !!parsedAmounts[Field.CURRENCY_B]
                          ? 'danger'
                          : 'primary'
                      }
                      width="100%"
                    >
                      {error ?? 'Supply'}
                    </Button>
                  </AutoColumn>
                )}
            </AutoColumn>
          </CardBody>
        </Wrapper>
      </AppBody>
      {pair && !noLiquidity && pairState !== PairState.INVALID ? (
        <AutoColumn style={{ minWidth: '20rem', marginTop: '1rem' }}>
          <MinimalPositionCard showUnwrapped={oneCurrencyIsWBNB} pair={pair} />
        </AutoColumn>
      ) : null}
    </>
  )
}
```

I am not sure on how this should be done. Any ideas on what I could do?

Thanks

Comment: Try reading the [Help article *How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's not just good advice for asking a StackOverflow question, it's good advice for debugging, and you're also more likely to get a response on StackOverflow.

Comment: That being said, I don't see obvious problems, but it's a lot of code to look at. Often this is caused by conditionally calling hooks, but I don't see that happening here. We can't see the full error - notably what is different between the renders.You should paste the full error text in the question (not a screenshot).

Comment: Lastly, you should put `await estimate()` in a `useEffect()` hook. Keep in mind that statement runs every render, which means it runs whenever any state or props change. This means that it is creating a loop in your code - whenever `estimate()` is called and doesn't fail, it sets state, which generally triggers a re-render (though in this case it might now), causing `estimate()` to get called again...